# Qr factorization in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am a newbie here and here is the following example, I am trying to replicate..

```
    val A = DenseMatrix((1.0, 1.0, 1.0), (4.0, 2.0, 1.0), (16.0, 4.0, 1.0))
    val QR(_Q, _R) = qr(A)
```

And my implementation in scala is:

```
object qr_factorization {
  def qr_factor(A: RowMatrix,nrows: Int, ncols: Int):(Any, Any) = {
    val rows = A.rows.map(_.toArray).collect().flatten
    val dense_matrix = DenseMatrix.fill(nrows, ncols)(rows)
    println(dense_matrix)
    val QR(_Q, _R) = qr(dense_matrix)
    return (_Q,_R)

  }

}
```

RowMatrix is from spark api https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix

When I try to compile the above, I get the error:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter impl: breeze.linalg.qr.Impl[breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix[Array[Double]],VR]
[error]     val QR(_Q, _R) = qr(dense_matrix)
[error]                        ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

Not sure, I understand the error :(

Comment: Can you post the full code?

Comment: What is the output of `println(dense_matrix)`?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no QR() implementation on the RowMatrix in the public API library, however there is "tallSkinnyQR". this QR is optimised for tall skinny matrix which is often the case of bigdata matrices(rows are much bugger than columns)

call like this:

```
def qr_factor(A: RowMatrix,nrows: Int, ncols: Int):(Any, Any) = {
.....
.....
val QR= qr(dense_matrix)
(QR._1,QR._1)

 }
```

By the way, there is no need for `return` in Scala, in general.